# PYTHON: Problema de iniciante: TRABALHANDO EM LISTAS

Tags: python, lista

Estou estudando programação, e estou tendo problemas, gostaria de saber se alguém pode me ajudar.

Estou assistindo aulas de lógica e algoritmos, porém a aula é toda em 'Portugol', e a linguagem que estou me dedicando neste início é Python. Muitos comandos são bastante diferentes, então achei interessante para aprender lógica e buscar soluções para a linguagem ao mesmo tempo. Porém, me deparei com um problema. Estou estudando listas, e preciso tirar a média de valores contidos dentro de uma lista. A conta é simples, pegar a altura de todas as pessoas digitadas pelo usuário, somar, e dividir pelo número de usuários, resultando na média de altura. Porém, o resultado está dando incorreto, e estou há muitas horas procurando algum erro / solução, e não consigo enxergar.

Alguma boa alma que tenha bons conhecimentos em python pode me ajudar?

Segue meu código:

```
nomes = [0]*10
idades = [0]*10
alturas = [0]*10

n = int(input('Quantas pessoas serão digitadas? '))
print()

for i in range(0, n):
    p = i + 1
    print(f'Dados da {p}ª pessoa:')
    nomes[i] = input('Nome: ')
    idades[i] = input('Idade: ')
    alturas[i] = input('Altura: ')
    print()

for i in range(0, n):
    soma = 0
    soma = float(soma) + float(alturas[i])
    media = float(soma) / n

print(f'Altura média = {media}.')
```

Comment: O problema é que você está zerando a variável `soma` toda vez que passa pelo loop. Basta movê-la para fora do loop.

Comment: @RenanGomes MUITO OBRIGADO!!! (y)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Mude isso:

```
for i in range(0, n):
    soma = 0
    soma = float(soma) + float(alturas[i])
    media = float(soma) / n
```

Por isso:

```
soma = 0
for i in range(0, n):
    soma = float(soma) + float(alturas[i])
    print(soma)
    media = float(soma) / n
```

Comment: MUITO OBRIGADO!!!